# Modifying elements using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is what I can see in chrome inspector. it's a simple line element.

How can I modify `x2="120"`? and change it to `220` for example?

```
<line id="uniqueDomId-276" x1="0" y1="0" x2="120" y2="0" stroke-width="1" stroke="#385D8A" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-linecap="flat" stroke-linejoin="round" data-stroke-sharpened="true" transform="translate(0.5, 0.5)" data-accepts="events" data-reactid=".0.0.3.2.0.1.0:$_player=16czu6OSdRsI=16IS5kYU7fKF.0.3:$c234.1:$c255.$slideobject274.$0.$0.$0"></line>
```

Note: I can select the line element using this code:

```
var item = $('[aria-label="Myline"] svg')
```

I just wonder how to change the `x2` attribute of it.

Comment: [attr](https://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Comment: .attr("x2","220"); doesn't work... please help... any idea what i've missed

Answer (score 0):

```
$('[aria-label="Myline"] svg').attr("x2","220");
```

Comment: It set the attribute.  It does not mean that the line was redrawn.

Comment: @SaraRee, [you can see that it does](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/n0jtp7a2/). If you have a question about updating the line after the change, feel free to post a new one.